# MS Graph permission required to read group[id]/planner/plans, but all requested permissions are granted

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use MS Graph to work with Planner tasks, and am currently investigating the API with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)prior to writing any code. I'm at the point where I'm trying to list all Planner plans for a given group, using the query [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{c6a12d05-ac5d-4e84-a924-f8be570d75d4}/planner/plans](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bc6a12d05-ac5d-4e84-a924-f8be570d75d4%7D/planner/plans). I'm getting a 403, but when I look under the Modify Permissions tab I already have all four of the suggested permissions:
[image: Query results]

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**
This is the error response:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "You do not have the required permissions to access this item.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2023-01-13T14:48:07",
        "request-id": "61a39484-fd91-47da-be0f-7e6d5e6e9955",
        "client-request-id": "d912b37f-b872-3753-e7f6-f4000d8e7998"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does the response json contain any code on the error property?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the error response - I can't see anything obviously relevant in it, but I'm new to Graph so that means nothing!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the screenshot in the permissions page, the following permissions Group.Read.All and Group.ReadWrite.All are not admin consented as seen in the screenshot below

[image]

Please ask your admin to grant you those permissions.